# Scroll vertical pinchando en el fondo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

¿Hay alguna forma por medio de jQuery o CSS de realizar el scroll vertical pinchando en el body de la página?

Tengo hechos y modificados los scroll del proyecto pero no tengo ni idea de cómo capturar el evento de pinchar en el body y que mueva el scroll.

Mi código:

```css
.layerManagementVarious::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  background: <?php echo $color3 ?>;
}

.layerManagementVarious::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #eee;
}

.layerManagementVarious {
  display: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 72vh;
  margin-top: 28px;
  width: 72%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="layerManagementVarious col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
  <!--<div id="layerTask">-->
  <div class='first'>
    <div class="containerColumn">
      <div class="titleContainer">
        <div class="list-img">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="vertical_center t-a-center"><img src="../uploads/users/foto.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-middle">
          <span class="list-name"></span>
          <span class="list-description"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="taskContainer">
        <div class="taskRecipient" data-id="1">
          <div class="miniTaskImageRecipient">
            <div class="miniTaskImage"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="miniTaskTitle">TITULO TITULO </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='first'>
    <div class="containerColumn">
      <div class="titleContainer">
        <div class="list-img">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="vertical_center t-a-center"><img src="../uploads/users/oto.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-middle">
          <span class="list-name"></span>
          <span class="list-description"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="taskContainer">
        <div class="taskRecipient" data-id="1">
          <div class="miniTaskImageRecipient">
            <div class="miniTaskImage"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="miniTaskTitle">TITULO TITULO </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='first'>
    <div class="containerColumn">
      <div class="titleContainer">
        <div class="list-img">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="vertical_center t-a-center"><img src="../uploads/users/foto.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-middle">
          <span class="list-name"></span>
          <span class="list-description"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="taskContainer">
        <div class="taskRecipient" data-id="1">
          <div class="miniTaskImageRecipient">
            <div class="miniTaskImage"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="miniTaskTitle">TITULO TITULO </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='first'>
    <div class="containerColumn">
      <div class="titleContainer">
        <div class="list-img">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="vertical_center t-a-center"><img src="../uploads/users/foto.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-middle">
          <span class="list-name"></span>
          <span class="list-description"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="taskContainer">
        <div class="taskRecipient" data-id="1">
          <div class="miniTaskImageRecipient">
            <div class="miniTaskImage"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="miniTaskTitle">TITULO TITULO </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='first'>
    <div class="containerColumn">
      <div class="titleContainer">
        <div class="list-img">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="vertical_center t-a-center"><img src="../uploads/users/foto.jpg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-middle">
          <span class="list-name"></span>
          <span class="list-description"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="taskContainer">
        <div class="taskRecipient" data-id="1">
          <div class="miniTaskImageRecipient">
            <div class="miniTaskImage"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="miniTaskTitle">TITULO TITULO </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código que tienes actualmente para que te podamos ayudar. Si puedes simplificar tu código dejando los elementos más relevantes para que lo podamos reproducir sería ideal, ya que te podremos ayudar mucho más fácilmente.

Comment: ¿A dónde quieres que se mueva cuando se pulse en el body?

Comment: Si haces click y mantienes pulsado moviendo el raton hacia la derecha que se mueva hacia la derecha y si lo mueves hacia la izquierda hacia la izquierda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a un gran compañero he dado con la respuesta:

se puede hacer con jquery:

```
    $('.layerManagementVarious').on('mousedown', function(e){ 

        var initialMousePosX = e.pageX;
        var initial_scroll=$('.layerManagementVarious').scrollLeft();
        var currentMousePosX=0;

        $(document).on('mousemove', function(ev){

            currentMousePosX = ev.pageX - initialMousePosX ;
            $('.layerManagementVarious').scrollLeft(initial_scroll+currentMousePosX);
        });

        $(document).on('mouseup', function(ev){
            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
            $(document).unbind('mouseup');

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes probar con el siguiente codigo y ya nadamas cambias las variables que se adapten a tu codigo

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('.nav');

$window.on('scroll', function(){
var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
prev = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: He intentado adaptar el codigo pero no me funciona: 
        var prev = 0;
        var layer = $('.layerManagementVarious');
        var nav = $('.layerManagementVarious');

        layer.on('scroll', function(){
            var scrollTop = layer.scrollTop();
            nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
            prev = scrollTop;
        });